# Find duplicate parent rows by evaluating child record set

Tags: c#, sql-server, linq, linq-to-sql

I am trying to find rows in table `parent` who's `child` records make it a duplicate of another record in the parent table.  So it's similar to a group by with count > 1, except the criteria is based on whether the child records match. In my example table diagram below you'll see I have three data columns, but only two of which I want to use in the comparison.

Tables/Columns:

- Parent

  - parentID
- Child

  - fkParentID
  - field1
  - field2
  - field3 (ignored)

I am open to using MS SQL, C# or LINQ to SQL

Comment: Do you want to see where there is 100% overlap for all children, or only where the same individual child exists with 2 parents?

Comment: @JNK - When there is 100% overlap.

Comment: I started working on a solution for this but it grew a bit and I don't have time to see it through.  My recommendation would be to make a CTE that lists all children that are dupes of other children, then find any parentIDs who don't have kids in that subgroup of duplicate children.

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - I don't understand your question. Could you try rephrasing it?

Comment: @Peter: Do you want to find all duplicate parents with the same childrens for a given `ParentID` ?

Comment: @BogdanSahlean - I was thinking just in general for all parents.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a silly Northwind Example:

```
Select 
ods.OrderID 
, derived1.Quantity
, derived1.Discount 
, derived1.SETKey
, TotalsItemsInThisSet = derived1.MYC
, ThisSetCardinal = ROW_NUMBER()  OVER(PARTITION BY derived1.Quantity, derived1.Discount ORDER BY derived1.Quantity, derived1.Discount) 
from 
    dbo.[Order Details] ods
    join
    ( select Quantity, Discount , COUNT(*) as MYC , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (Order by Quantity, Discount) AS SETKey from dbo.[Order Details] where Quantity > 50 and Discount > 0 GROUP BY Quantity, Discount Having Count(*) > 1 ) derived1
    on ods.Quantity = derived1.Quantity and ods.Discount = derived1.Discount
order by  
    derived1.Quantity, derived1.Discount
```

Results:

```
OrderID     Quantity Discount      SETKey               TotalsItemsInThisSet ThisSetCardinal
----------- -------- ------------- -------------------- -------------------- --------------------
10361       55       0.1           1                    2                    1
10451       55       0.1           1                    2                    2
10269       60       0.05          2                    9                    1
10273       60       0.05          2                    9                    2
10419       60       0.05          2                    9                    3
10492       60       0.05          2                    9                    4
10570       60       0.05          2                    9                    5
10590       60       0.05          2                    9                    6
10637       60       0.05          2                    9                    7
10865       60       0.05          2                    9                    8
11012       60       0.05          2                    9                    9
10390       60       0.1           3                    4                    1
10485       60       0.1           3                    4                    2
10688       60       0.1           3                    4                    3
10845       60       0.1           3                    4                    4
10475       60       0.15          4                    4                    1
10693       60       0.15          4                    4                    2
10817       60       0.15          4                    4                    3
10990       60       0.15          4                    4                    4
10424       60       0.2           5                    4                    1
10567       60       0.2           5                    4                    2
10700       60       0.2           5                    4                    3
10847       60       0.2           5                    4                    4
10263       60       0.25          6                    7                    1
10263       60       0.25          6                    7                    2
10461       60       0.25          6                    7                    3
10802       60       0.25          6                    7                    4
10912       60       0.25          6                    7                    5
10918       60       0.25          6                    7                    6
11030       60       0.25          6                    7                    7
10854       65       0.15          7                    2                    1
10990       65       0.15          7                    2                    2
10339       70       0.05          8                    6                    1
10359       70       0.05          8                    6                    2
10605       70       0.05          8                    6                    3
10658       70       0.05          8                    6                    4
10658       70       0.05          8                    6                    5
11008       70       0.05          8                    6                    6
10395       70       0.1           9                    3                    1
10845       70       0.1           9                    3                    2
11033       70       0.1           9                    3                    3
10267       70       0.15          10                   4                    1
10324       70       0.15          10                   4                    2
10403       70       0.15          10                   4                    3
10543       70       0.15          10                   4                    4
10430       70       0.2           11                   2                    1
10773       70       0.2           11                   2                    2
10344       70       0.25          12                   3                    1
10372       70       0.25          12                   3                    2
10393       70       0.25          12                   3                    3
10359       80       0.05          13                   3                    1
10472       80       0.05          13                   3                    2
10865       80       0.05          13                   3                    3
10516       80       0.1           14                   2                    1
10765       80       0.1           14                   2                    2
10324       80       0.15          15                   2                    1
10633       80       0.15          15                   2                    2
10373       80       0.2           16                   2                    1
10847       80       0.2           16                   2                    2
10515       84       0.15          17                   2                    1
10983       84       0.15          17                   2                    2
10549       100      0.15          18                   2                    1
10854       100      0.15          18                   2                    2
11030       100      0.25          19                   2                    1
11030       100      0.25          19                   2                    2
10776       120      0.05          20                   2                    1
10894       120      0.05          20                   2                    2
10398       120      0.1           21                   2                    1
10451       120      0.1           21                   2                    2
```

Comment: Basically, for every "child table" duplicate ( based on Quantity Discount ), you get back all the Parents.  "SetKey" is the same value for anything that matches on the same ( Quantity Discount ).  "ThisSetCardinal" gives you a cardinal number ~within~ each set.

Comment: It's not a bad start. If I wanted to hand loop through records this would at least tell me which other parent records I needed to check.

Comment: " am trying to find rows in table parent who's child records make it a duplicate of another record in the parent table"        How isn't that the same as "at least tell me which other parent records I needed to check" ?

Comment: A parent usually has multiple child records. I want to find two or more parents with the exact same set of child records. This query as it is shows me every other parent that has a single matching child record.  Don't misunderstand, I appreciate the help, just answering your question.

Comment: Oh.... "same SET of children".........Gotcha. Hmmmm.  I'll have think about that one.